# AngularJS: (ng-)Hide an element but not its children

Tags: angularjs

How would one go about creating an ng-show like directive that would hide an element but not the child elements?

I was thinking if `url` variable exists angular template

```
<a ng-show-link="url" ng-href="{{url}}">
  <img ng-src="picture.png" />
</a>
```

would print out

```
<a href="/url">
  <img src="picture.png" />
</a>
```

, and if the `url` didn't exist

```
<img src="picture.png" />
```

. Would help cut out additional container elements when using with ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to have an `<img>` tag, and then write a directive to *wrap* it with an `<a>` tag if a url is present. Adding/wrapping is cleaner than removing existing tags.

Though with a tad bit of redundancy in your view you could also do this without a directive:

```
<a ng-show="url" ng-href="{{url}}"><img src="picture.png" /></a>
<img ng-hide="url" src="picture.png" />
```

Comment: I think i'll go with your second solution for the time being. Tried moving ng-src attribute into an <a> tag inside the directive for a bit but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom directive and apply it on the `<a>` tag and pass the url in an attribute.
If the url is not defined, use JQuery dom manipulation to remove the `<a>` and keep `<img>` in it's place.

Although it is much simpler to just disable the  link or use `javascript:;` in its place. Trying to remove the `<a>` is kind of premature optimization.